# How to load picture from @drawable to ImageView using fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

How to load picture from @drawable to ImageView using fragments?
In every single fragment I have other picture. With array of String that's works, but with pictures doesn't. It's only returns 0.

XML Array (PS.  also doesn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/one</item>
        <item>@drawable/two</item>
    </array>
</resources >
```

XML View:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15" />
```

JAVA:

```
public class ShowElements extends Fragment {

    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;
    String[] authorsNicks;
    int[] imageMain;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...
        authorsNicks = res.getStringArray(R.array.authors_nicks);
        imageMain = res.getIntArray(R.array.images);
        return...
   }

public void updateArticleView(int position) {
        TextView autorTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.author);
            autorTextView.setText(authorsNicks[position]);

         //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.one); It load picture
        image.setImageResource(imageMain[position]); //No picture in view
        Log.i("qwerty",String.valueOf(imageMain[position])); // 0 in LogCat

        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the full code and exceptions or errors if any

Comment: I don't have any errors. Just can't see image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the next:

> public class ShowElements extends Fragment {
>
> ```
> final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
> int mCurrentPosition = -1;
> String[] authorsNicks;
> TypeArray imageMain;
> ```
>
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
>             ...
>
>     authorsNicks = res.getStringArray(R.array.authors_nicks);
>     imageMain = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
>     return...    }
> ```
>
> public void updateArticleView(int position) {
>           TextView autorTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
>                   R.id.author);
>               autorTextView.setText(authorsNicks[position]);
>
> ```
>      //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.one); It load picture
>     image.setImageResource(imageMain.getResourceId(position, -1)); //It should load your picture
>     Log.i("qwerty",String.valueOf(imageMain[position])); // 0 in LogCat
>
>     mCurrentPosition = position;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

```
TypedArray typedArray = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

...

image.setImageDrawable(typedArray.getDrawable(position, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be defining drawable ids in resources as array is your requirement. but why to struggle that much to save id array in resources and get them using `Resources` and `TypedArray` and setting programmatically?

you can define your drawable id array programmatically and use it.

```
public class ShowElements extends Fragment { 
     .......
     private static final int[] imageMain = new int[]{R.drawable.one,R.drawble.two};
     ......
     public View onCreateView(......) {
             ........
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use
                 getResources().getDrawable(R.id.myImage);

Comment: But I want to set more pictures than one